# Footer menu not showing in Safari

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile, safari

The site in question is: http://www.twisted-perfectionism.com

I have this #secondary_nav which should appear at the bottom of the screen on mobile devices.
It's working fine in both Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari it doesn't appear at all. Using Developer Tools I can see that it is placed correctly but it's invisible. I'm a newbie.. Please help!

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 880px) { [...] #secondary_nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(../images/trans.png) repeat;
}

#secondary_nav > ul {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#secondary_nav > ul > li {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}

#secondary_nav ul li ul {
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#secondary_nav ul li ul li a {
    text-align: left; 
} [...] }
```

The problem was fixed by removing:

```
overflow: auto;
```

The footer appears now, but on iOS, when scrolling down, the iOS bottom bard disappears and the footer doesn't come down until i take my finger off the display.

See screenshot: http://s29.postimg.org/7r49yfzc7/Photo_17_05_14_02_06_16.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wotks if you take out the overflow: auto in the style for #control, it's cutting of the #secondary_nav:

```
#control {
        width: 34%;
        min-width: 300px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: auto; /* Take this out */
        -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 1px 7px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .7);
                box-shadow:  0px 1px 7px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .7);
        background: url(images/trans.png) repeat;
}
```

As far as I can tell it doesn't mess up anything else either.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I will mark it as resolved soon.

Comment: @ralph.m But there is one more issue that bugs me: when i scroll down and the iOS bottom navigation bar dissapears, there is a slight delay of 1-2seconds before the footer menu comes down. See the attached screenshots: http://s16.postimg.org/pfrfo59ol/fix.png http://s29.postimg.org/7r49yfzc7/Photo_17_05_14_02_06_16.png

Answer (score 0):

On line 1068 of your stylesheet the `#footer` is set to `display: none` and there's nothing to override that on small screens. (On desktop browsers, an inline style of `display: block` is inserted.)

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue using kalyan's response, but i've encountered another problem. please check the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me you html markup?

But by the way try this

```
    @media only screen and (max-width : 880px) { 
     #secondary_nav {
       width: 100%;
      height: 12px;
      padding-top: 16px;
      position: absolute; /* Try with absolute positioning*/
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: url(../images/trans.png) repeat;
     }
    }
```

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue using kalyan's response, but i've encountered another problem. please check the comment. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this !important rule:

```
#control {
    width: 34%;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0!important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    z-index: 999 !important; 
    overflow: auto; /* Take this out */
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 1px 7px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .7);
            box-shadow:  0px 1px 7px 0px rgba(00, 00, 00, .7);
    background: url(images/trans.png) repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The footer appears now, but on iOS, when scrolling down, the iOS bottom bard disappears and the footer doesn't come down until i take my finger off the display.

See screenshot: http://s29.postimg.org/7r49yfzc7/Photo_17_05_14_02_06_16.png

Comment: Ok... IOS can not update the new location when you scroll down! I suggest you to try this little jquery script! :) - https://gist.github.com/davemo/1644510

Comment: And something that i noticed in windows phone... when you scroll down, the background image shakes until you stop the animation... it´s a bit weird... but all the rest it´s perfect!! :)

Comment: @Leagues thank you for your support. I've tried the code from github but it's not working. Are you sure that should do the trick? To be honest I'm not entirely sure I've implemented it correctly either.. :(

Comment: Forget that... i found something probably better, with only css... have a look here - http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ - sorry about the other link... it has some dependencies.